# yadcf_data not populating select filter

Tags: yadcf

I'm using server-side processing and trying to populate select filter.
I'm using a custom datatables `fnServerData` function (modified version of [elastic-datatables](https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables)) in order to use elastic search. My `fnCallback` function looks like this:

```
fnCallback({
    'draw': parseInt(draw),
    'recordsTotal': response.hits.total,
    'recordsFiltered': response.hits.total,
    'data': dataSet,
    'yadcf_data_2': [{
        value: "Trident",
        label: "Trident Eng'"
    }, {
        value: "Tasman",
        label: "Tasman Eng'"
    }]
});
```

For now I'm just using dummy values taken from your example response (also tried the simpler option of string list instead of value/label objects), but the select filter still has 0 value to choose from (column index is correct).
Any idea how custom callback could mess things up?

You can see the whole function without my modifications [here](https://github.com/pidupuis/elastic-datatables/blob/master/src/jquery.elastic-datatables.js)

Datatables setup:

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "sDom": 'lrtip',
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100],
            [10, 25, 50, 100]
        ],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "order": [
            [1, "asc"]
        ],
        "columns": [...],
        'fnServerData': $.fn.dataTable.elastic_datatables({
            index: index,
            type: type,
            client: client
        })
    });

yadcf.init(table, [{
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "range_date",
        datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker',
        filter_plugin_options: datetimepickerOptions
    }, {
        column_number: 1,
        filter_type: "text",
        text_data_delimiter: ","
    }, {
        column_number: 2,
        filter_default_label: "Select Filter"
    }, {
        column_number: 3,
        filter_type: "text",
        text_data_delimiter: ","
    }]);
```

Comment: yadcf can listen to datatables [events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/), so the yadcf_data_XYZ values are being processed only at the [xhr](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event, I don't know how to listen to the fnCallback, if there is a way let me know.

Comment: I just checked xhr event with .on('xhr.dt', fun...) and the json object does contain yadcf_data_2 along with all the other info I gave to callback. Still nothing though.

Comment: you should debug the `xhr.dt` event kistener in yadcf and try to figure out waht happens there (maybe its being overriden for some reason) see code here https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L3332

Comment: [isDOMSource(oTable)](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L3302) is true in my case. Not sure what it means, but my table sure is in initial dom.

Comment: It means that I'm not listening to xhr event because lack of serverSide: true. Will see how to detect you case. Plz post ur datatables setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added support for this in [0.9.0.beta.1](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/36dd5e2a7e2713cf9983ce475e71e73d6b47ef4c/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) so it should work now

Comment: Thanks. It works, but ever since version 0.8.9, the yadcf has given me an error on startup, so I have used older version (0.8.8.beta5). I took a screenshot. Not sure what it breaks, but for example pagination doesn't work. [Screenshot](http://pasteboard.co/1zxpdWt8.png)

Comment: please open an issue on github with the relevant data (screenshot / line code / sample if possible / dt setup / yadcf setup)